# whitelisting public load balancer to specific IPs

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-elb, convox

For the time being I don't want anyone to be able to access my apps on convox rack. But I do want to put it into production. Is the whitelist parameter on a rack the way to do this?

https://docsv2.convox.com/reference/rack-parameters#whitelist

and then I can just set the parameter to my IP address?

When I try to use this, I get the error

```
Updating parameters... ERROR: direct rack doesn't support update, make sure you are not using RACK_URL environment variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about convox, but if you have access to the AWS account running the load balancer, you can modify the inbound rules of the load balancer's security group to restrict HTTP/S access to specific IPs.

Here's a step-by step guide: [Security groups for your Application Load Balancer](https://go.aws/3QmCxdj)